# Get value of mySQL query grouped by id

Tags: mysql

I want to know an efficient way to solve the following query. Essentially I have the following two classes

```
CREATE TABLE `example`.`doc` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `uuid` INT NOT NULL,
    `creator` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

CREATE TABLE `example`.`pic` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `docuuid` INT NOT NULL,
    `taken_at` DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `lat` DECIMAL(3,10),
    `lon` DECIMAL(3,10),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

this two tables are related by uuid (I know this is not the best idea to link two tables, but the table is like this). uuid is unique per doc. With the following query

```
SELECT
    `doc`.`id` AS `docId`,
    `doc`.`uuid` AS `uuid`,
    `doc`.`creator` AS `creator`,
    COUNT(`pic`.`id`) AS `pics`,
    MIN(`pic`.`taken_at`) AS `min_date`,
    MAX(`pic`.`taken_at`) AS `max_date`
FROM
    `doc` INNER JOIN
    `pic` ON (`doc`.`uuid` = `pic`.`docuuid`)
WHERE (
    `pic`.`docuuid` IS NOT NULL AND
    `doc`.`uuid` IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY `doc`.`uuid`
```

I get, for each doc, the date at witch the first and last pics was taken. Additionally I want to get in this query, for each doc, the latitude and longitude of the first and last pic taken at that doc.

For example, If I have

```
doc1 = (id=0, uuid=1)
doc2 = (id=1, uuid=2)
pic1 = (taken_at=2021-01-01, docuuid=1, lat=1, lon=2)
pic2 = (taken_at=2021-01-02, docuuid=1, lat=3, lon=4)
pic3 = (taken_at=2021-01-03, docuuid=2, lat=5, lon=6)
pic4 = (taken_at=2021-01-04, docuuid=2, lat=7, lon=8)
pic5 = (taken_at=2021-01-05, docuuid=2, lat=9, lon=10)
```

then I want to get for doc1 minLat=1, minLon=2, maxLat=3, maxLon=4 and for doc2 minLat=5, minLon=6, maxLat=9, maxLon=10

Comment: Post your expected results for this sample data in tabular format. Also, what is your version of MySql?

Comment: `DECIMAL(3,10)` says "3 digits, 10 of which are to the right of the decimal point.  That is impossible.  `(9,6)` is more reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mat continue by joining the results of your current query with the `pics` table and extracting the desired details of each `pic`, I've included a sample below:

```sql
SELECT
    t.*,
    earliest_pic.lat as minLat,
    earliest_pic.lon as minLon,
    latest_pic.lat as maxLat,
    latest_pic.lon as maxLon
FROM
    (
SELECT
    `doc`.`id` AS `docId`,
    `doc`.`uuid` AS `uuid`,
    `doc`.`creator` AS `creator`,
    COUNT(`pic`.`id`) AS `pics`,
    MIN(`pic`.`taken_at`) AS `min_date`,
    MAX(`pic`.`taken_at`) AS `max_date`
FROM
    `doc` INNER JOIN
    `pic` ON (`doc`.`uuid` = `pic`.`docuuid`)
GROUP BY `doc`.`uuid`
) AS t 
INNER JOIN `pic` as earliest_pic ON earliest_pic.taken_at = t.min_date AND
                                    earliest_pic.docuuid = t.docId
INNER JOIN `pic` as latest_pic ON   latest_pic.taken_at = t.max_date AND
                                    latest_pic.docuuid = t.docId
```

Let me know if this works for you

Comment: Just have to add an AS t after the first FROM and earliest_pic.docuuid = t.uuid, thank you!!

Comment: Thank you. This has been added. Glad that this was helpful

Comment: The `WHERE` clause is unnecessary -- neither will be NULL  Also, you should suggest index(es), else performance will be bad for large tables.